# Automating conversion from .SHP to .GPX for thousands of shapefiles?

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, convert, gpx

I am looking for a way to automate conversion from .Shp to .Gpx. I know how to save a shapefile into gpx in a layer, but it would take too much time to do 1 by 1 as we might receive thousands of shapefiles that need conversion.

I am not very prone in coding, especially in QGIS, so does anyone have an idea or maybe even a code to make this possible with QGIS?

Comment: Do you have to use pyqgis or could you make use of the commandline ogr2ogr converter directly?
`ogr2ogr -f GPX out.gpx in.shp`
With a little batch scripting you can loop through the files/folder and convert everything in one.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in qgis with gdal convertformat in the processing plugin:

```
processing.runalg("gdalogr:convertformat","input_shp", 16, "FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES","output_gpx")
```

Now for your case you have a lot of layers, all you have to do is to make it in a loop